# What is shot noise related to?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

I have a question about the shot noise and i encountered that when i was studying about squeezed state of light and beam splitters and homodyne detection and etc. but my question is :
Is the shot noise related to quantum measurements or is it related to quantum fields ? or both ? or none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot noise arises when the thing you're measuring is quantized and can be modeled as a Poisson process (for example, when you're measuring the number of photons received by a sensor, where each photon has the same probability of being detected by the sensor). Because no detector is perfectly efficient (i.e. the probability of detecting a given photon is never exactly 1), even if the rate of incident photons is constant, your *measured* number of photons will fluctuate with each measurement, where the fluctuations follow a Poisson distribution. The magnitude of these fluctuations is called *shot noise*. It's not necessarily a quantum phenomenon, since even a detector of discrete classical objects like ping-pong balls will still have shot noise. It's due to the discreteness of the measured objects and the probabilistic nature of detection from any real detector.

In the particular case of photons hitting a detector, the *existence* of photons can be labeled as a quantum phenomenon, but the shot noise is merely a statistical consequence of the existence of photons.